# How to implement Multithreading/Multiprocessing in Python by merging the function

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

The dictionary and code is below which is working

- The question is regarding mainly on multithreading, I know that below code can be easily rewrite to easy way. But the ask is on multithreading, I just created one working example to test
- total(todos) is the main function
- user_count , title_count , complete_count  are independent of each other
- I need to implement multithreading/multiprocessing has to implement
- def total(todos): is the place where need to do multithreading

```
todos = [{'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'A', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'B ', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'C', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'A', 'completed': True},
     {'userId': 2, 'id': 1,'title': 'B', 'completed': False}]
def total(todos):
    ###### Multithreading need to implement ##########
    user_count = userid(todos)
    title_count = title(todos)
    complete_count = completed(todos)
    search_count_all = {**user_count, **title_count, **complete_count}
    return search_count_all
def userid(todos):    
    for d in todos:
        for l, m in d.items():  
            super_dict.setdefault(l, []).append(m)
    d = {k:len(set(v)) for k,v in super_dict.items()}
    return {"userid":d['userId']}
def title(todos):    
    for d in todos:
        for l, m in d.items():  
            super_dict.setdefault(l, []).append(m)
    d = {k:len(set(v)) for k,v in super_dict.items()}
    return {"title":d['title']}
def completed(todos):    
    for d in todos:
        for l, m in d.items():  
            super_dict.setdefault(l, []).append(m)
    d = {k:len(set(v)) for k,v in super_dict.items()}
    return {"completed":d['completed']}

total(todos)
```

Current output and expected output

```
{'userid': 2, 'title': 4, 'completed': 2}
```

can we do multprocessing also

> > from joblib import Parallel, delayed

Comment: Which part of your code do you want to multithread? Do you want to perform the various calculations inside the `total` function in different threads?

Comment: @mandulaj  def total(todos):

Comment: @sim check my answer, it points another issue you have and didn't pay attention to

Comment: @ChenA. its working, fine thanks, arg=1 means func2(i) is this is arg

Comment: This is *not* a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- `super_dict` is not defined. How do you expect anyone to run this? Notice that none of the answers deal with your actual code. But I will tell you this: Notwithstanding the answers you have already gotten, multithreading will not help much because this is CPU-intensive and there will be contention for the Global Interpreter Lock. You need to use multiprocessing and the solution will be rather complicated.

Comment: Are you aware of the differences between multiprocessing and multitasking especially in the context of Python? Which one of do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mandulaj answer specifies, you can use the library as follows. I simplified the example, so it's easier to reason.

I wrote 3 different functions, where each just multiply the input value by a different number. Then using the [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) I submitted their execution, concurrently.

You then need to collect the results of the each execution. This is done with the `as_completed` method from the library.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed


def func1(i):
    return i


def func2(i):
    return i*2


def func3(i):
    return i*3


funcs_to_execute = [func1, func2, func3]
arg = 1
res = []

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(f, arg) for f in funcs_to_execute}

    for fut in as_completed(futures):
        res.append(fut.result())

print(res)

>[2, 1, 3]
```

To apply it for your use-case, the function you submit is `userid, title, completed` with the arg `todo`. The results of all of them resides in the `res` list container.

**However, there are few issues with your code** when you enable concurrency. It's currently working for you, because it runs sequentially. The `superdict` is shared, and when accessed concurrently, is not guaranteed. You can fix this by creating a new list in every function, return it as a result, and at the end, aggregate. So something like this

```py
def userid(todos):
    res = list()
    for d in todos:
        for l, m in d.items():
            if l == 'userid':
                res.append(m)

    return {"userid": res}
```

and the merge the results from `futures` (which are, dictionaries) into a single `superdict`.

Comment: arg = 1
is func2(i), is this the arg?

Comment: `arg = 1` is the argument you want to pass to your functions. In your example it's the `todos`

Comment: FYI, on CPython, accessing `superdict` concurrently with `.setdefault()` is totally fine. GIL for ze rescue!

Comment: @Bharel I find it bad paradigm. Accessing globals concurrently (not only for reading) is a place where bugs like to hide. Personally, if I'm not forced to use it, I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

Check out pythons [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) library. You can run your function as a thread with

```
import concurrent.futures

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future1 = executor.submit(userid, todos)
    future2 = executor.submit(title, todos)
    # ...

    user_count = future1.result()
    title_count = future2.result()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment to your question, you really should be using multiprocessing rather than multithreading since your tasks are CPU-intensive. The problem then becomes sharing a global `super_dict` dictionary since, unlike with multithreading, each subprocess has its own memory space and `super_dict` must now be located in shared memory. The way to go about initializing this is to use a `dict` instance returned by the `multiprocessing.SyncManager` and to then initialize each subprocess with a proxy to this managed dictionary when the process pool is created. This method will work for both Windows and Unix-based platforms. This version of the dictionary has some limitations. It does not seem to support the `setdefault` method and `append` method the way you would want it to in that the proxy does not seem to realize that the dictionary has actually been updated. So, a few adjustments have to be made.

But there is a great inefficiency in your code. Each of your functions `userId`, `title` and `completed` perform the same redundant processing of the `todos` list against the `super_dict` dictionary adding multiple occurrences of user ids, titles, etc. This doesn't ultimately matter because you are counting the number of unique values. But it is wasteful of CPU cycles to do this redundantly and in the multiprocessing scenario you now have the problem of handling the parallel updating of the dictionary that buys you nothing. The following code therefore just initializes `super_dict` in the main process. And your functions `userId`, `title` and `completed` are doing more calculations than they need to, which can be further simplified (see below).

**When one is done improving the efficiency of the code, it does not pay to actually even bother with multiprocessing for this particular example since the overhead of creating the pool and proxy dictionary is greater than any savings from executing these three trivial functions in parallel. But this, at least, shows you the technique for a *real* example.**

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager


def init_pool(d):
    global super_dict
    super_dict = d

def total(todos):
    # Call to Manager() returns a SyncManger instance:
    with Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        init_dict(d)
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(d,)) as executor:
            f1 = executor.submit(userid)
            f2 = executor.submit(title)
            f3 = executor.submit(completed)
            user_count = f1.result()
            title_count = f2.result()
            complete_count = f3.result()
            search_count_all = {**user_count, **title_count, **complete_count}
            return search_count_all

def init_dict(the_dict):
    for d in todos:
        for l, m in d.items():
            # Cannot use setdefault:
            if l in the_dict:
                # Use this instead of append:
                the_dict[l] += [m]
            else:
                the_dict[l] = [m]

def userid():
    return {'userId': len({v for v in super_dict['userId']})}

def title():
    return {'title': len({v for v in super_dict['title']})}

def completed():
    return {'completed': len({v for v in super_dict['completed']})}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    todos = [{'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'A', 'completed': False},
         {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'B ', 'completed': False},
         {'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'C', 'completed': False},
         {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'A', 'completed': True},
         {'userId': 2, 'id': 1,'title': 'B', 'completed': False}]
    print(total(todos))
```